# Appium: How to find installed app's package name and its main Activity in Appium?

Tags: automated-testing, mobile, appium, uiautomation

For mobile application automation I am using appium and in that following things are mandatory:

```
    WebDriver wd;
    File app=new File("Path\\to\\WhatsApp.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"");
    dc.setCapability("deviceName", "MOTO X");
    dc.setCapability("plateformVersion", "4.4.4");
    dc.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    dc.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());     

    dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.whatsapp");
    dc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.whatsapp.Main");

    URL url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    wd=new AndroidDriver(url, dc);
```

That is OK for whatsapp as we can easily get but i wanted to know that how could i know any **activityname** for **default contact dialler,camera** or any other default inbuilt functionality? Also how could i know xpath/id (like we do get in browser) in mobile app?
Is there any one who could help me with that? i am just beginner to appium.Thanks!

Comment: you need to use Appium inspector to find elements ID , Xpath etc..

Comment: Here is my answer about how to find out package name and activity: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/12382/7163 , I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use UIAutomator. This will give you package name of currently active app. UIAutomator can be found at Android/sdk/tools/ .After launching UIAutomator, click on device screenshot button. But make sure, your device is connected to your system and debug mode is enabled. For Camera app, it gives package name as `com.sec.android.app.camera`

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, assuming you have your android SDK properly set up.

Steps to follow:

1. Go to the terminal (command line)
2. Then type `aapt d --values badging <path-to-apk-name>`

This will basically print out the info out of the androidmanifest.xml file.
You can locate the **package name** at the top of the contents of the file displayed.Then if you scroll further down the screen, you will find **launchable-activity**, which displays the name the name of the main activity.

P.S. - If you have any further doubts, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

For finding the application package and Activities you can use the `App info` application from google play store  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.migali.soft.apkinfo

Answer (score 0):

1) From Google Play Store, Search and Install "[Apk Info free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.migali.soft.apkinfo)" app.

2) Launch Apk Info free app and you can grab packge name & app activity of your targeted application

3) Ui Automator is there for finding xpath and id of an element but it supports or works only on MAC system, for windows u must communicate with ur develelopers.

Comment: Both the answers have already been given.

Answer (score 0):

Another great option is to use the **hierarchyviewer** tool. Look at SDK/tools. Just open it and then open the app in the device or emulator.
example:
com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
before / is the package, after / is the activity.

Comment: I'm not an android guy, but why doesn't this answer the question? It appears to be an alternative way to gather the same information, unless there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Based on my research, this is a valid answer. It's a bit light on detail and could be improved, but using the Hierarchy Viewer tool does appear to be a valid way to retrieve the package name and main activity.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/) is an article that describes two different ways to find appPackage and appActivity.

I personally used the first technic and it's working pretty well. Here is what you should do:

1. Connect your phone to your computer.
2. On your phone, open the app you want to know the appPackage and appActivity of.
3. On your computer, open a shell and type `adb shell`
4. On this same shell, type `dumpsys window | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'`

Here are the results you should be obtaining:

[image: mCurrentFocus=Window{c838a23 u0 appPackageName/appActivityName}]