# Android App testing with appium

Tags: android, appium

I am testing android app using appium. Everything is working fine but I want to know as tester that how can I get below parameters of APK :

1 - app-package

2 - app-activity

If you are using appium then you know that we have to define above 2 things in code to test app. At this stage , I need to ask value of above both to developer.

Is there any way that I can get value of those parameter directly? so it would like no need to ask to developer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to use **adb** (Android Debug Bridge) tool (part of Android SDK). So, install application under test on target Android device or emulator. And you should run application to get current activity and package name. So, after running app execute the following commands from command line (android-sdk/platform-tools/adb):

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|FocusedApp'
```

And you will get something like this:

`mCurrentFocus=Window{43270790 u0 com.estrongs.android.pop/com.estrongs.android.pop.view.FileExplorerActivity}
  mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{44d67b88 token=Token{435e5990 ActivityRecord{434ee320 u0 com.estrongs.android.pop/.view.FileExplorerActivity t133`

So, current activity is **com.estrongs.android.pop/.view.FileExplorerActivity** and application package name is **com.estrongs.android.pop** is this case.

**Steps:**

1. Install apk on device or emulator
2. Run application
3. Execute `adb shell` from command line
4. Execute command to get current activity from device(shell) shell:

`dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|FocusedApp'`

I hope it helps you.

Comment: That command it for windows Os?

Comment: Do you need for Windows? Because grep is linux command. If you want Windows command use **findstr** instead of **grep**

Comment: Or you can do the following:
`adb shell`
And than:
`dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|FocusedApp'`

Comment: ok thanks a lot. Should I replace any value with your given command or can use directly as it is?

Comment: You're welcome! You may use directly. So, again. First command is `adb shell` and the next command after first is: `dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|FocusedApp'`

Comment: @HelpingHands, steps added to my answer :)

Comment: From, where I need to run this command?dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|FocusedApp' , I am using genymotion emulator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21840/discussion-between-amazpyel-and-helping-hands).

Answer (score 3):

If you can install 3rd party App on phone or emulator , I recommend you to install "[Apk Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intelloware.apkinfo&hl=en)"  It always help me to get package and activity.

Answer (score 0):

App package name can be found in the application manager of the mobile device. find the app in the app manager and get the package name in the information.
Activity name can be found in many ways 
You can always try the dalvik log/ android monitor logs/ ddms log. Just randomly tap on a button of the application the log will show you some corresponding activity for that app. There you can find the activity name in the Application tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `aapt` (Android application packaging tool) to find out the name of the package and the launchable activity.Just follow these steps:

1. Go to your command prompt, assuming you are on *NIX based systems.
2. Then type

   ```
   aapt dump badging <path-to-apk> | grep package:\ name
   ```

   This will give you the app-package.

   ```
   aapt dump badging <path-to-apk> | grep launchable-activity:\ name
   ```

   This will give you the lauchable activity of the app.

Answer (score 0):

1）**adb shell am monitor**: *And then start the APP that needs to obtain the package name.*

2）**adb shell dumpsys window | findstr mCurrentFocus**：*View the currently running package name and startup window name.*

3）**adb shell dumpsys activity | findstr mFocusedActivity**: *Same as above.*

4）**adb shell “dumpsys window | grep mCurrentFocus”**

5）**adb shell "dumpsys activity | grep mFocusedActivity"**